# run docker container as a arbitrary user passed to it while running the image

Tags: docker

I want to run a docker container as an arbitrary user which is passed to the image while running it. For example `docker run -u 1000 myimage`.

The above is possible. However I want to create a home directory with this user 1000 while starting the container(possibly through CMD) and do my container service stuff within that directory.

Is this possible and some pointers would be useful on ways to achieve it.

Comment: Docker _by design_ hides these details from the container process, and the ways to work around it completely ignore basic Linux security constraints.  If specific user IDs and host-filesystem content are important to you, it will be easier to just not use Docker.

Comment: How are you logging into a preexisting docker container as an arbitrary user? Wouldn't that user already have to exist in the container before you log in as it?

Comment: @Alon its not necessary for the user to exist.

Comment: @user2599052 please see my answer. It handles such cases where the user does not exist in the container.

Answer (score 0):

First save your current user and group in variables:

```
export uid=$(id -u)
export gid=$(id -g)
```

Then to run your image,you have two options:

1) Run the image from the location of the app directory itself:

```
sudo docker run -d \
 --user $uid:$gid \
 -v $(pwd):/home/$USER \
 --workdir="/home/$USER" \
 myimage
```

2) Create a new directory for the app, e.g. at /home/$USER/app, but then you will have to write in command line your CMD from the docker file.

For example if this was your Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:7
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json /app
COPY . /app
CMD node bin/www
```

Your would run it like that:

```
sudo docker run -d \
 --user $uid:$gid \
 -v $(pwd):/home/$USER \
 --workdir="/home/$USER" \
 hello-express \
 bash -c "cp -rf /app/* /home/$USER/; node bin/www"
```

Here you pass the user to the container using $uid:$gid and you mount the user's home directory as a volume and then set it as the working directory.

I know it's quite complex, but it's the only way to achieve exactly what you want.

If you want a simpler solution, consider planning it differently. See [this example](https://gist.github.com/alkrauss48/2dd9f9d84ed6ebff9240ccfa49a80662) for running a docker container as a non-root user.